# PayPal Express Customer Checkout Transaction ID

Tags: perl, paypal

I'm using PayPal Express checkout and I'm trying to display to the customer their transaction id at the end of the checkout process on the thank you page.

I'm currently pulling back:

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TRANSACTIONID
```

Which is the transaction id that is logged in my business account. However the transaction id on the email sent to the customer is different to this id that is being returned.

I'm using this API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

The documentation states

"(Optional) Transaction identification number of the transaction that was created. You can specify up to 10 payments, where n is a digit between 0 and 9, inclusive.

Note This field is only returned after a successful transaction for DoExpressCheckout has occurred.

TRANSACTIONID is deprecated since version 63.0. Use PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TRANSACTIONID instead. "

I'm also using

```
 PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM
```

Which is very helpful and lets me put my order reference number into the main body of the email that the customer receives, but I'd also like their transaction id, so that if they send a query through this can be logged in a field in the database and cross referenced against the order with just the transaction id.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal assigns different transactions to the buyer and the seller.  I'm not exactly sure why, but I know they do.

If a customer gives you their transaction ID, though, you CAN find it in your PayPal account by doing a search through paypal.com or via the TransactionSearch API.

Comment: GetTransactionDetails would find it, too, and provide more detail.